# How to copy image attribute from one data source to another in wakanda with script?

Tags: wakanda

I use this code to copy data from one Data Class to another :

`sources.dataClass1.attribute1 = sources.dataClass2.attribute1;`

it work for all attribute type except image, how to copy image attribute from one data source to another ?

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using this script :

```
 var ds1 = ds.dataClass1.first(); 
 var ds2 = new ds.dataClass2();
 ds2.image = ds1.image;
 ds2.save();`
```

Comment: but i still see nothing on the image type attribute,
any other solution?

Comment: the code is work if i put it on .js file on server side, how do i call the script from my app page ? i'm a new wakanda user and can't find it in the documentation.